# Can't ssh to GitLab ee in a docker container

Tags: ssh, docker, gitlab

I've installed GitLab ee on Docker. I'd like to use authentication via ssh instead password but each time I try to authenticate, connection is closed. SSH Port is `1122->22` so I'm connecting with `git@gitlab.example -p 1122`. I also enabled the port in ufw, checked if openssh server is running in the container.

Error: `Connection closed by HOST port 1122`

I was searching long time but I didn't find anything so I'll be glad for any suggestion.

Thank you.

## EDIT

Log from `ssh -T -vv git@gitlab.example.com -p 1122`

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to HOST:1122 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by HOST port 1122
```

Comment: Add `-v` or `-vv` to your `ssh` command to get debug information about why the connection failed.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman There's nothing special. Added log to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this issue by updating GitLab ee docker image and starting ssh server in it. I don't know why, but it doesn't start automatically.